# Finding ImageHandle of an uefi shell app. or module

Tags: bootloader, bios, firmware, uefi

I have a uefi shell app and a uefi module, providing similar functionality, I am trying to merge them into a single entity that can be executed either as a module from Boot Menu or from uefi shell.
Is it possible to create an efi app that can be executed like this ?

The entry point for module is

```
ModMain (
  IN EFI_HANDLE        ImageHandle,
  IN EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE  *SystemTable
  )
```

while for uefi shell app. it's,

```
MyAppMain (
  IN UINTN            Argc,
  IN CHAR16           **Argv
  )
```

Can I get the ImageHandle of an efi image implicitly (something like This pointer in C++ objects) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is the "module" in UEFI? There are only 2 types of UEFI binaries - UEFI application and PXE driver; If I did understand the question correctly I would do the following:

- The "module" is a regular UEFI app that parses **argv;
- Main UEFI App LoadImage() the "module" and passes the handle as a command line argument;